# Android Chrome touch objects don't persist between events

Tags: android, google-chrome

I've developed a web app which has some touch handling code built in.  On touch down, it saves a reference to the changedTouches in the event.  On touch up, it iterates through the changedTouches and tries to match them to a stored touch object from the touchDown event, signaling the end of a touch.  It seems that the touch objects are not the same across the two events though, meaning I cannot match up the touches.  The app works great in iOS, and in Safari and Chrome on the desktop with some touch event simulation.  Just seems to be a problem in Chrome on Android.

Here's an example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMj32/5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of touches in TouchLists is not guaranteed to remain consistent. You should be relying on the `touch.identifier` instead. Please see the [touch events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#widl-Touch-identifier).

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in Chrome for Android where the touches and changedTouches array don't maintain their own unique identifier correctly, unless you apply `event.preventDefault()` on the touchmove or touchstart event.

This bug affects Chrome for Android in Ice Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean, and has remained unresolved for over a year. So, the first poster is correct, you should rely on `touches[i].identifier` or `changedTouches[i].identifier`, keeping in mind that you must call `event.preventDefault()` on touchmove or touchstart in order for those identifiers to persist correctly.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827